Почему у меня при изменения миграции возникла ошибка в laravel 10?
Почему у меня при миграции возникла ошибка в laravel 10? Я создал миграцию в Laravel 10, которая изменяет тип столбца с integer на string в БД.
Но когда я запускаю миграцию, то у меня происходить ошибка.
   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException 

  Declaration of Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase::connect(array $params, $username = null, $password = null, array $driverOptions = []) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::connect(array $params): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/PDO/Concerns/ConnectsToDatabase.php:22
     18▕      * @return \Illuminate\Database\PDO\Connection
     19▕      *
     20▕      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     21▕      */
  ➜  22▕     public function connect(array $params, $username = null, $password = null, array $driverOptions = [])
     23▕     {
     24▕         if (! isset($params['pdo']) || ! $params['pdo'] instanceof PDO) {
     25▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Laravel requires the "pdo" property to be set and be a PDO instance.');
     26▕         }

      +1 vendor frames 

  2   [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()

Можете подсказать в чем может быть причина.
Прикладываю файл с миграцией
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('baskets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id_finance_program')->default(0)->nullable()->after("is_credit")->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('baskets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_finance_program')->default(0)->nullable()->after("is_credit")->change();
        });
    }
};


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Исправил. Убрал картинку.

Какая СУБД? PostgreSQL, например, не поддерживает ->after("is_credit").

Я на данный момент использую СУБД Mysql.

Судя по всему, несоответствие версий Illuminate и Doctrine. Класс Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase объявлен как потомок Doctrine\DBAL\Driver, но параметры функции connect не соответствуют. В PHP 7.2 это было предупреждением, а с 7.4 - ошибка.

как запускаешь миграции? возможно там какой то внешний пакет, не помню точно
и запускать надо так doctrine:migrations:migrate
проверить через php artisan list есть ли у тебя эта команда.

Вы можете решить проблему понизив doctrine/dbal to 2.13.1, у вас сейчас скорей всего 3.1.0.
Подробнее решение этой проблемы можете посмотреть здесь
